# Symlinked index.php does not load in apache2

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-14.04, symlink

I've installed `apache2` and `php5` (and any other components that were needed) and set up a little home webspace on an `ext3` drive. I created an `index.php` file as a custom file listing page. When I type in the address `http://localhost/` I am presented with said `index.php`, no problems. I then make a symbolic link of my `Music` folder from another part of the `ext3` drive into my webspace. Example:

```
ln -s /home/edward/Music /home/edward/www/
```

When I refresh `http://localhost/` I see the `Music` folder there. When I click that "link" I am presented with `403` as expected. I then make a symbolic link of `index.php` into the `Music` folder, and when I click on the `Music` "link" it still gives me `403`. I remove the symbolic `index.php` and actually copy (`cp`) the `index.php` into the `Music` folder and Then I'm presented with the content of the `Music` folder.

So, what am I missing to make `apache2` register symlinked web files? I have set the option `FollowSymLinks`. Are there more than one?

Comment: Why the symlinks? Im not really sure what you  are trying to achieve.  Can you not place the actual index.php in your web root and read the link to music and be done with it?

Comment: @useyourillusiontoo To have the same page occur in multiple folders, and as I edit the master all the others get the exact same update.

Comment: So you're creating a filesystem indexer?

Comment: @useyourillusiontoo Yeah, that is for a good number of folders, but not all. Some folders may contain a different `index.php`, and some folders I'd like to leave `403`.